# MapReduce to bulk update a datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I need to bulk update a datastore with a CSV file (250,000 rows) using Python. From researching this area, I can see that MapReduce would suit this problem.

I have found some examples showing similar actions but can't seem to find an example of how to do a simple Bulk Update of a datastore using this library.

Do you know of any examples in this area or would you be able to point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the [bulk uploader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) to upload data from csv to the datastore.

Comment: Thanks Shay for the suggestion. I use bulk uploader to upload CSV files to the datastore, but I am not sure if the bulk uploader can handle an Update statement specifically!

Comment: Shay, thanks for responding, as far as I can see, the bulkuploader can only do bulk upload/download. Do you have any examples of how it can do an Update by any chance please? Thanks

Comment: @JimmySnatch if you use the same key the items will be updated (or upload and overrride). Whats the differences between that and "update"?

Comment: @ Shay - thanks for the suggestion, really appreciate it and I can see exactly what you are talking about, however the problem is that I can't find any documentation to set the key name whilst bulkloading!

Comment: pls ignore my last post, I was being really stupid! Got it now, thanks again for the suggestion. Can't believe the solution was that easy, I was making it way too complicated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

mapreduce can yield mapreduce.operation.db.Put(entity) as iterator, app engine can handle the update in a very efficiently manner. Or you can just put db.put(entities) in your mapreduce method. Sounds like to me, you are reading data from a file and update all the related entities, mapreduce probably is not the best tool for that.

Comment: Hi Yuan, yes you are correct, I am reading data from a file and updating all the related entities in a datastore. If Mapreduce is not the method to use, what method would you suggest? Thanks